# ERROR: Windows named pipe error: The pipe has been ended. (code: 109)

Tags: docker

How can I resolve this error? I'm using Docker, whenever I do 'docker-compose up' the containers are running for a second then it constantly stops then shows the error:

> ERROR: Windows named pipe error: The pipe has been ended. (code: 109)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below worked for me. I'm running Docker on Linux containers. Docker Desktop version 4.14.0 (91374)

I did a switch to Windows containers, waited for the restart, and then switched back to Linux containers.

[image]

No idea why that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check volume path it is already locked

Comment: what does this mean